# How can I get the interval between two dates as "yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss"

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, time

How can I get the interval between two dates as "yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss"

If I use

```
 SELECT TIMEDIFF(UploadedDate,Verification_Date) AS 'delay' from table;
```

The results are

```
 25:20:13
```

Can I view this as 0000:00:01 01:20:13 ?

Does anyone have an idea about this query?

Comment: If this is only a concern of the *representation* of data, it should be done in your application, not the database.

Comment: DATEDIFF results no.of days only......it can be done in app but an automatic loop should run in an event of mysql. So need via query only